# Explode the string to array in php

Tags: php

I have a string

```
string(22) ""words,one","words2""
```

and need to explode to an array having structure

```
array( [0] => words,one ,[1] => words2)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @andreas I tried explode function ie, explode("," , $string); But the result is array(3) { [0]=> string(6) ""words" [1]=> string(4) "one"" [2]=> string(10) " "words2" " }

Comment: Good enough for me.

Comment: Try like this : https://eval.in/945566

Comment: Do you expect this to have more then 2 groups? Also, will the input string always have an extra pair of quotes around the whole thing.

Comment: you can also try `preg_split("/\",\"/", trim($str, '"'));`

Comment: How are you creating this string ?

Answer (score 4):

To continue on the `explode` option you mentioned trying, you could try the following:

```
$str = '"words,one","words2"';
$arr = explode('","', trim($str, '"'));

print_r($arr);
```

Notice the `trim` to remove the beginning and ending quote marks, while `explode` uses the inner quote marks as part of the delimiter.

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => words,one
    [1] => words2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `""` is a typo for `"\"` or `'"`.
I use regex to capture what is inside of `"` with `(.*?)` where the `?` means be lazy.
I escape the `"` with `\"` to make it read them literal.
You will have your words in $m[1].

```
$str = '"words,one","words2"';

Preg_match_all("/\"(.*?)\"/", $str, $m);

Var_dump($m);
```

https://3v4l.org/G4m4f

In case that is not a typo you can use this:

```
Preg_match_all("/\"+(.*?)\"+/", $str, $m);
```

Here I add a `+` to each of the `"` which means "there can be more than one"

Comment: I need the result as array(3) { [0]=> string(9) ""words,one" [1]=> string(10) " "words2" " }

Comment: There is more `"` than in your original string. Is that really correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) you can try :

```
$str = '"words,one","words2"';
$matches = preg_split("/\",\"/", trim($str, '"'));

print_r($matches);
```

check : https://eval.in/945572

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the the input string can be broken down as follows:

- The surrounding double-quotes are always present and consist of one double-quote each.
- "words,one","words2" is left after removing the surrounding double-quotes.

We can extract a csv formatted string that `fgetcsv` can parse.

---

Trimming the original and wrapping it in a stream allows us to use `fgetcsv`. [See sample code on eval.in](https://eval.in/945579)

```
$fullString= '""words,one","words2""';
$innerString = substr($fullString, 1, -1)
$tempFileHandle = fopen("php://memory", 'r+');
fputs($tempFileHandle , $innerString);
rewind($tempFileHandle);
$explodedString = fgetcsv($tempFileHandle, 0, ',', '"'); 
fclose($tempFileHandle);
```

---

This method also supports other similarly formatted strings:

- [""words,one","words2""](https://eval.in/945579)
- [""words,one","words2","words3","words,4""](https://eval.in/945582)